# Защита от CSRF-атак и подделки данных

Tags: php, token

Здравствуйте, написал от руки такой скрипт.
По идее, он должен защищать от CSRF-атак путём генерации токена и хэша на странице, далее проверяем данные на стороне сервера. Верны ли мои предположения?

**edit.php**

```
<?
// остальное
    $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand() . microtime())); // токен на стороне клиента
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
$uniquekey = 'tutprivatkey123';
$hash = md5($_SESSION['user_id'].$topic['user_id'].$topic_id.$uniquekey); // хэш на стороне клиента
?>
 <script>
        // closing topic script
        $(function(){
            $('#close').click(function(){
                var close = 'act=close&user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>&author_id=<?php echo $topic['user_id']; ?>&topic_id=<?php echo $topic_id; ?>&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&hash=<?php echo $hash; ?>'; //
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "ajax.php",
                    data: close,
                    success:function(msg){
                        $('.msg_box').text(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $('.msg_box').text(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <span class="msg_box"></span>
<div id="close" class="button large">Закрыть объявление</div>
```

**ajax.php**

```
if ($_POST['act'] == 'close') {
    $topic_id = $_POST['topic_id']; // К какому объявлению относится
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // Посетитель
    $author_id = $_POST['author_id']; // автор темы из ПОСТ данных
    $token = $_POST['token']; // токен из ПОСТ данных
    $hash = $_POST['hash']; // хэш из ПОСТ данных
    $uniquekey = 'tutprivatkey123'; 
    $hash2 = md5($_SESSION['user_id'].$author_id.$topic_id.$uniquekey); // новый хэш из тех же данных

    if(@count($rate_db) == 0 AND ($user_id == $author_id) AND ($token == $_SESSION['token']) AND ($hash == $hash2))
    {
        $close = $pdo->exec("UPDATE topics SET closed =1 WHERE id =$topic_id");
        echo 'good';
    }
    else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: Скажите плюсы и минусы данного способа, пожалуйста, не кидайтесь камнями.

Comment: Ты посему в сесию токен не записал?

Comment: Есть же:)
3 строка:
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;

Comment: @Naumov чекай сообщение выше)